# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() when hitting the URL

Tags: php, html

I have two pages as of now called `index.php` and `checkout.php`.

In the index.php page, I have 2 checkboxes and 4 radio buttons.

What I am doing is, When the user checked the checkbox and radio buttons and clicks on the submit button then I am sending the value of checkboxes and radio buttons to the `checkout.php` page
and that values will call my query to display the output on my checkout page.

I tried to send the data from one page to another page using `SESSION` and it is working. I am getting the `POST` data my check out page and I am getting the output of my query as well.

Now my issue is, If I refresh the page then there is no issue but when I hit the URL then I am getting the error

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
> /home4/test/example/checkout.php on line 70

**index.php**

```
<form action="checkout.php" method="post" name="form1">
    <div class="formWrapper">
        <div class="form-group">
            <fieldset>
            <input type="checkbox"  name="fruit[1]"  value="1"><label>Fruit One</label><br />
            <input type="radio"  name="color[1]"  value="1"><label>Black</label>
            <input type="radio"  name="color[1]"  value="2"><label>Yellow</label>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <fieldset>
            <input type="checkbox"  name="fruit[2]"  value="2"><label>Fruit Two</label><br />
            <input type="radio"  name="color[2]"  value="1"><label>Black</label>
            <input type="radio"  name="color[2]"  value="2"><label>Yellow</label>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Next">
    </div>
</form>
```

**checkout.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
 include('connection.php');
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 $_SESSION['fruits']=$_POST['fruit'];
 $_SESSION['colors']=$_POST['color'];
  
  foreach ($_SESSION['fruits'] as $key => $value) {
  try{
     $sqlquery="SELECT col1,col2, (select demoCol from tbl_colors where c_id=:c_id) as demoColor FROM tbl_mytable WHERE id=:id and is_active=1";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sqlquery);
     $stmt->execute( array(':c_id' => $_SESSION['colors'][$key],':id'=>$_SESSION['fruits'][$key]) );
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
     foreach ($result as $row) {?>
        <h3><?php echo $row['col1'];?> <?php echo $row['col2'];?></h3>
        <p><?php echo $row['demoColor'];?></p>
<?php
     }
 }
 catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
  }
}
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: which is line 70? `foreach ($_SESSION['fruits']` or `foreach ($result as`??

Comment: Also your query logic is a little skewed. Create the `prepared statement` once before the loop and call with different values in the loop. But that said you are embedding variables directly in the sql itself which kindof defeats the purpose of the prepared statement

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius, I am getting issue in this  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sqlquery); which is in try block

Comment: you know there is a curly brace missing too?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius, Yes i forgot to add that in the question. added now

Comment: which is line 70?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius, I am learning the PHP, I search on google and tried this code. Can you help me with correct way?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius, line no 70 is $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sqlquery);

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection. It's very disappointing that you seem to be aware of PDO and Prepared Queries, yet are still injecting raw values into your queries instead of passing them as parameters to `execute`...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, I though If I am using PDO then SQL Injection is not required.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, OK so I have to pass the session in the $stmt->execute().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking through your code quickly I think you could modify it a little

```
<?php

    session_start();
    /*
        `fruit` and `color` MUST be available
        before attempting to assign as any 
        sort of variable - so test here!
    */
    if( isset( 
            $_POST['submit'],
            $_POST['fruit'],
            $_POST['color']
        )){
        
        
        include('connection.php');
        /*
            It is not entirely clear why you would want to assign
            session values directly from POST values when you could
            simply work with the POST values instead.
        */
        $fruits=$_POST['fruit'];
        $colours=$_POST['color'];
        
        /*
            create the sql statement with placeholders
            which are then bound as parameters when the
            statement is executed.
            
            Create the statement once and assign new values
            inside of any loops rather than re-stating it
            on each iteration.
        */
        $sql='select `col1`, `col2`, ( select `democol` from `tbl_colors` where `c_id`=:cid ) as `democolor`
                from `tbl_mytable`
                where `id`=:id and `is_active`=1';
        
        $stmt=$pdo->prepare( $sql );

        
        
        /*
            Process the POSTed variables
            using the $key to access the values
            within the other array ( colours )
        */
        foreach( $fruits as $key => $value ) {
            try{
                if( isset( $colours[ $key ] ) ){
                    $stmt->execute( array(
                        ':cid'  =>  $value,
                        ':id'   =>  $colours[ $key ]
                    ));
                    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
                    foreach( $result as $row ) {
?>
                    <h3>
                        <?php echo $row['col1'];?>
                        <?php echo $row['col2'];?>
                    </h3>
                    <p><?php echo $row['demoColor'];?></p>
<?php
                    }
                }
            } catch( PDOException $e ) {
                echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Closer inspection suggests that you could probably have just a single SQL query to retrieve all the records by initially processing the POST data and generating suitable strings containing the various IDs in order that you use the `IN` operator in the sql - such as  `where id IN (1,2,3)` etc - like:

```
$sql='select `col1`, `col2`, ( select `democol` from `tbl_colors` where `c_id` IN ( :cids ) ) as `democolor`
        from `tbl_mytable`
        where `id` IN ( :ids ) and `is_active`=1';
$stmt=$pdo->prepare( $sql );

$args=array(
    ':cids' =>  implode(',',array_values( $colours ) ),
    ':ids'  =>  implode(',',array_values( $fruits ) )
);

$stmt->execute( $args );
```

I hope this may be of use - I should stress that none was tested so there could be errors but hope not.

Comment: Give me sometime to understand your answer.

Comment: Yes, I implement your answer with my code, I need to understand                 $stmt->execute( array(
                    ':cid'  =>  $value,
                    ':id'   =>  $colours[ $key ]
                ));

Comment: I think i have to use like this $stmt->execute( array( ':cid' => $colours[ $key ] , ':id' => $fruits[ $key ] ));

Comment: In PDO you can bind variables to the statement in a few ways - `bindParam`, `bindValue` or by assigning an associative array to the `execute` method with keys matching the placeholders in the sql statement.

Comment: Got it, I tested your first solution and now when i hit the URL then I am getting blank. I can't use you a second solution because I have two tables and I am sending the id from one table to the second table to get the selected rows

Comment: I think blank is enough for this kind of event... Is it ok?